# How to checkout and reset using smartgit?

Tags: checkout, reset, smartgit

Need help in understanding the below

1). How do i check out to a particular commit and again revert back to the recent commit ?

Tried branch->checkout->same branch and check out to the previous commit, but when i did this the commits made after the one i checked out now got lost !

Its not in the list to checkout to recent commit !

2). How do i reset my head to a particular commit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Usually, branch refs won't be changed by a **Check Out**, so you may use **Check Out** again to switch back to your branch: simply select the corresponding branch for "Showing Branches" selector.

If the branch ref to your old head is actually lost, you can open the Log and use **Query|Load All Commits** to display all such heads, then add a temporary branch ref to the corresponding head and check out this head.

(2) **Local|Reset** should work for you.