# overwrite other branch(github) in Smartgit

Tags: git, github, overwrite, smartgit

I am new on smartgit-ubuntu and I have a problem. I started to use smartgit for gui. I have a project on github and I have 2 branches which are master and new branch. I cloned project on smartgit and I changed code in new branch. Also, I pushed code to new branch and code is on github-new branch. I did mistake and I want to overwrite new branch with master code. In sum, I want to change new branch code with master code and I want to push it to github-new branch. How can I do? Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset your local new branch to master, then force push it.
An example of [reset with SmartGit is seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32412764/6309).

Even without smartGit, you can do that in command-line:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout newBranch
git reset --hard master
git push --force -u origin newBranch
```

---

However, as the OP comments:

> This reset deletes github commits and copy `master` to other branch.
>   Namely I want to commit all `master` code to other branch in github and I don't want to delete past commits

In that case, you can:

- find the commit that newBranch was referencing *before* being reset: see "[Recover from `git reset --hard?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24236065/6309)"

That is:

```
git checkout newBranch
git reflog show
git reset --hard <oldSHA1 of newBranch>
```

- [checkout the files from `master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15536640/6309) (while staying in newBranch)

  ```
  git checkout newBranch
  git checkout master -- .
  ```

(note the final `-- .`: "dash-dash-space-dot" at the end of the second checkout)

- add, commit and push: you will add, commit and push files from `master` in `newBranch`, while keeping the history of `newBranch`.
  If you had already pushed newBranch before, you will need to force the push

  ```
  git push --force
  ```

Comment: is there  any way to overwrite local branch and push it to github. This reset deletes github commits and copy master to other branch. Namely I want to commit all master code to other branch in github and I don't want to delete past commits.

Answer (score 1):

In any `git` to get a branch to point to a specific commit (including another branch) you need to `reset`. Specifically in `smartgit` [How to checkout and reset using smartgit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213343/how-to-checkout-and-reset-using-smartgit#6214927) indicates you should have **reset** in your `gui` - just checkout the new branch, and reset it to master.