# I removed files from local instead of discarding local changes

Tags: git, smartgit

I made a big mistake. I wanted to remove all my local changes but instead of discarding them I just selected all files and removed them. I use SmartGit.
How can I return that files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore your local filesystem state to the latest change in git. Do this by "resetting" your load repository:

```
git reset --head HARD
```

I'm not familiar with SmartGit specifically, but this question covers resets in SmartGit: [How to checkout and reset using smartgit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6213343/how-to-checkout-and-reset-using-smartgit)

Comment: I did `git reset --hard HEAD ` .
Thank You a lot.